Reports and Dashboards in LWR Experience site
I understand and have used the Dashboard and Reports component in an Aura Experience Site - but I am struggling to display them in an LWR Experience.
I have moved the CRM Analytics Dashboard component to the page, but no dashboards are available to show. I had a look at the Analytics Studio Dashboards, and they are there. Does this component allow Standard Dashboards to show?
Does it have a link to the Report under it? Users need to see the report itself as well as be able to be taken to a Report config page.
First time I am trying this in LWR. If I am completely off the mark, please do point me in the right direction.
If they are not - is it possible to do with Flexcards at all?

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_enable_wave.htm&type=5 and https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_analytics_limitations.htm&type=5 are good reads
